# Finding a convergent subsequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ using a Fubini argument

Tags: sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I am new to solving non trivial-for me,at least- theorical problems,so I Have  kind of general trouble, when constructing a proof, to see if all passages are correct. In particular, I tried to prove the following statement and I would need either a check to my solution or a new one if my attempt is not correct.

Let $(f_h) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$  a sequence of functions converging in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ to $0$, i.e.

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f_n(x,y)|\,dxdy=0$

Prove there exists a subsequence $f_{h(k)}$  such that, for almost everywhere $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the sequence

$g_{h(k)}^x(y)= f_{h(k)}(x,y) \;$

converges to $0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ ,which is  $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_{h(k)}(x,y)|\, dy=0 $ for almost anywhere $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Here my attempt:

By fubini theorem , we get that:

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f_n(x,y)|\,dxdy= \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x,y)|\,dy)\,dx \to  0$

as $n$ approaches to infinity. This is equivalent to say that the sequence of function of $x$ ,

$w_n(x)= \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x,y)|\, dy$

tends to $0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. By a well known corollary to Riestz-Fisher theorem there exists a 
subsequence  $w_{h(k)}$ such that

$\lim_{k \to \infty} w_{h(k)}(x)=0 \qquad $    for almost anywhere $x \in \mathbb{R} $

which is equivalent to

$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f_{h(k)}(x,y)|\, dy = 0 \qquad$ for almost anywhere $x \in \mathbb{R}$

which is the desired result.

Comment: Your proof looks good.